# Dynamically append query parameters to URL on POST with .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I have a very simple html form that, upon submission, should redirect the user to another page. There's a field in the form, which value needs to be appended to the redirect Url (via query string) IF the user has entered a value.

So, if the user enters "hello" in the form, they would be redirected to "mysite.com?x=hello", else it would just direct to "mysite.com?x=". Currently my code is ignoring the IF statement within my POST, can anyone see what the issue is?

Here's my code:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="test" name="test" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

if(IsPost){
    var x = Request.Form["test"].IsEmpty() ? false : true;

    if(x){
        x = "hello";
    }

    Response.Redirect("http://www.mysite.com?x=" + x);
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that [`method="get"`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp) will also append inserted values as parameters to the URL. If you have only have one input, you could just change the form-`method`. Also, in your code, the `x` is first a Boolean, and later you assign a string.

Comment: C# doesn't allow you to assign a string to a variable that was a boolean before. The `var` keyword doesn't work the way it works in JavaScript, for example, it's just syntactic sugar so that you wouldn't have to type `bool` instead; the variable is still of that one type, though, not "any type".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code won't compile as you try to assign a string (`"hello"`) to the boolean `x` (`true` / `false`), but you only assign it when `x` is false, i.e. when `Request.Form["test"]` is empty.

Try this:

```
string redirectTo = Request.Form["test"];
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(redirectTo))
{
    redirectTo = "hello";
}

Response.Redirect("http://www.mysite.com?x=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(redirectTo));
```

It's a bit unclear what you want exactly to happen from your question, but you must be able to figure it out from here. If you want to redirect to `?x=` when the input is empty, simply remove the `if` block as  `Request.Form["not entered item"]` will return `null`.

As @ChrisK comments on your question, there are better ways of doing this.

Comment: @Rubens added that, but I'm not sure whether the rest of your edit is what OP wants, question's a bit unclear. I tended to keep the format as much as in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You're checking `IsPost` but it should be `IsPostBack`.

See this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article for reference.